# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on ARM

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, rosserial, gumstix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried getting ROS to run on ARM systems, such as Gumstix or Phidget SBCs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10716/ros-on-arm/) by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) on 2011-07-25**:
Check out eros: http://www.ros.org/wiki/eros or rosserial:http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

EROS is a project devoted to enabling easy cross compiling of ROS projects for non-X86 architectures.  It assumes that you are running a full Linux distro on your ARM.

rosserial on the other hand allows you to communicate using ros on platforms that do not have a full linux stack. It is meant to send messages over serial to a computer.  Our primary platform for rosserial is Arduino which runs on an 8-bit microcontroller.

If you are using a Gumstix Overo or similar platform, you want to use EROS.

---

Originally posted by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) with karma: 508 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2011-07-26**:
Is EROS able to run navigation stack successfully on full embedded linux now?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros running on an iPhone/iPad. Did cross-compilation with rosmake under Mac OS X. Works like a charm. You will have to patch the serialization.h though. At least on these ARM devices there will be a misalignment crash otherwise... See https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2883

---

Originally posted by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) with karma: 191 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rado0x54](https://answers.ros.org/users/708/rado0x54/) on 2011-07-26**:
Yeah, that would definitely be nice.

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-07-26**:
Thats interesting, I'd only discovered that problem on a really obscure samsung board. Given iphone/ipad prevalance, we'll have to try and work out a proper way to patch that and get it into the mainstream sometime.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-04-03**:
How do you cross-compile ros for iOS using rosmake?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried running ROS on Beagleboard (xM) after installing Ubuntu on it.

---

Originally posted by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) with karma: 224 on 2011-07-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on 2011-08-09**:
Ahhh - so the cross compiling with EROS would potentially work faster than compiling on the beagleboard with ubuntu, right?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-05**:
Eros at the moment just enables cross compiling to make development faster for embedded boards.

**Comment by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on 2011-07-26**:
No, I installed ROS from  Source.  http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source

**Comment by [pjmartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/866/pjmartin/) on 2011-07-26**:
Did you need to use EROS to build ROS for your beagleboard?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've collected my notes and prepared a tutorial about [installing ROS on a Gumstix Overo](http://kfuresearch.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/installing-ubuntu-and-ros-on-the-gumstix-overo-fire/) from -literally- scratch :) Hope, it gives some idea...

---

Originally posted by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) with karma: 288 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-10**:
I completely agree. I'd love to here what your experiences are after some thorough testing.

**Comment by [Kadir Firat Uyanik](https://answers.ros.org/users/81/kadir-firat-uyanik/) on 2011-08-10**:
Snorri, I suppose it heavily depends on your application, particularly the way the memory is used. But I will try to swap off to test the board for various applications to have a more quantitative comparison. I'll check dropping rosout too.. Thanks for the advices...

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-05**:
You might want to drop rosout to reduce ram and do less writes (less redundant logging, but a little harder to debug with tools). See http://answers.ros.org/question/1034/roslaunch-without-rosout

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2011-08-05**:
You can safely try avoiding swap. I've had swap turned off on my dev usb pen drive embedded installations for about a year. So long as you're really not pushing your RAM limits, its ok. In fact, on slow drives I'd say your better off managing memory  than killing your flash with alot of slow writes.